# Jquery update all browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a private chat system everything works fine but i have a problem the chat boxes are not visible by default so once a user clicks on a name to chat i am using jquery to show that chatbo.

what i want is if i send a msg to the other person it should automatically change the chat box state from hide to show , lemme show you my code

```
    $('#send_now').live("keypress", function(e){
    me  = $(this);      
    if(e.which == 13)
    {
        getData();
    }
});

function getData(){
        var send_to = $(me).parent('#textareaPanel').children('#submit_send_to').val();
        var sender = $(me).parent('#textareaPanel').children('#submit_sender').val();
        var send_msg = $(me).val();

        var flick = '<div class="singleMsg"><p id="msgTop"><span class="name"><img src="images/avatar.png" width="15" height="15" alt="avatar" /> '+ sender +' said ---</span><span class="time"></span></p><p id="msgData">' + send_msg + '</p></div>';

        $('.' + sender).closest('#forclick').show();

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == '4' && xmlhttp.status == '200')
        {

            response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $(me).closest('#allMsgs').children('#fake').append(flick);
            $(me).val('');
        }
    }


    var send_msg = $(me).val();

    parameters = 'sender=' + sender + '&send_to=' + send_to + '&send_msg=' + send_msg;

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'scripts/chat-submit.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    }
```

what i am doing is once a person hits enter it will send the data to the server using ajax and then it will append that msg to the sender's screen now the problem is though the chat has been sent , the receiver is not sure because his chatbox is hidden so he will have to click my name to see are there any chats or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this until you long-poll server.

You can send ajax request every five seconds (even StackOverflow chat does it) to poll for the newest data

```
setInterval(function(){
    poll();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: i am doing that to grab the chats in a different function and that function is getting data for all the logged in users , so in that case it will make all the chat boxes visible though i am not sending chat to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting your code.

jQuery already has integrated function calls($.post,$.get shortcuts to $.ajax) which already can take care of using the appropriate XMLHttpRequest for user's browser, no need to do it all by hand, that is what libraries are meant for.

Secondly, genesis answer is the answer to your question.

Comment: what genesis said i am doing that, let see if i have 3 users online so poll function will get data for all 3 of those every 10 sec, if i try to show chat box div at that time it will make all of them visible without any reason

Comment: Use sessions unique per user and include the session identifier as a parameter for your polling code.